# Discover identically adjacent strings with regex and python

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Consider this text:

```
...
bedeubedeu France The Provençal name for tripe
bee balmbee balm Bergamot
beechmastbeechmast Beech nut
beech nutbeech nut A small nut from the beech tree,

genus Fagus and Nothofagus, similar in
flavour to a hazelnut but not commonly used.
A flavoursome oil can be extracted from
them. Also called beechmast

beechwheatbeechwheat Buckwheat
beefbeef The meat of the animal known as a cow

(female) or bull (male) (NOTE: The Anglo-
saxon name ‘Ox’ is still used for some of what
were once the less desirable parts e.g. oxtail,
ox liver)

beef bourguignonnebeef bourguignonne See boeuf à la
bourguignonne
...
```

I would like to parse with python this text and keep only the strings that appear exactly twice and are adjacent. For example an acceptable result should be

```
bedeu
bee balm
beechmast
beech nut
beechwheat
beef
beef bourguignonne
```

because the trend is that each string appears adjacent to an identical one, just like this:

```
bedeubedeu
bee balmbee balm
beechmastbeechmast
beech nutbeech nut
beechwheatbeechwheat
beefbeef
beef bourguignonnebeef bourguignonne
```

So how can someone search for adjacent and identical strings with a regular expression? I am testing my trials [here](http://www.regexr.com/). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(\b.+)\1
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL0cW7/1)

Or, to just match and capture the unique substring part:

```
(\b.+)(?=\1)
```

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL0cW7/2)

The word boundary `\b` makes sure we only match at the beginning of a word, and then match 1 or more characters other than a newline (in a singleline mode, `.` will also match a newline), and then with the help of a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) we match exactly the same sequence of characters that was captured with `(\b.+)`.

When using the version with a `(?=\1)` look-ahead, the matched text does not contain the duplicate part because look-aheads do not consume text and the match does not contain those chunks.

**UPDATE**

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/PLplTg):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\b.+)\1')
test_str = u"zymezyme Yeast, the origin of the word enzyme, as the first enzymes were extracted from yeast Page 632 Thursday, August 19, 2004 7:50 PM\nabbrühenabbrühen"
for i in p.finditer(test_str):
    print i.group(1).encode('utf-8')
```

Output:

```
zyme
abbrühen
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this correct answer. I wonder if there is also a feature to get the half of the string (since it would give the wanted result) with regex in order to save a second pass of the data for the final output. Thank you again `stribizhev`.

Comment: Excuse me, I think I should have posted this from the beginning: [`(\b.+)(?=\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/lL0cW7/2). Right?

Comment: No need thanking so much, upvoting is really enough :) BTW, you should have posted what you tried since I saw you tried something.

Comment: I now see that when I search with the proposed regex in this data: `zymezyme Yeast, the origin of the word enzyme, as
the first enzymes were extracted from yeast

Page 632  Thursday, August 19, 2004  7:50 PM` what I get is `[['zyme'], [], [], [' ', ' ']]`, i.e. it parses also the commas. I am using this code: `reg = re.compile(r"(\b.+)(?=\1)")
for line in textfile:
    matches += [(reg.findall(line))]
textfile.close()`, do you think this can be improved?

Comment: lso why '`abbrühenabbrühen'` is parsed as  `'abbr\xc3\xbchen'` ? How can I avoid these special characters parsed in this way?

Comment: Please see my demo. It is almost a must to mention the programming language you are working with at the beginning.

Comment: Another `bag` that I saw is that it catches also strings like `in` in `containing` so I guess we should set the boundary to be a line feed on the left and empty space on the right?

Comment: Maybe you need [`p = re.compile(ur'(\b.+)\1\b')`](http://ideone.com/CzupiF)? the first `\b` word boundary already helps filter out substrings inside a larger word.