# Regular expression when arabic Alphabet is included Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of ids which are like:

```
A5ukur+de2.008x١٥١١٠٦١١٥٠٥٢٤٦٢
```

and I have written the following commands that is using the group name,

```
>>> RE_SID = re.compile(ur'(?P<sid>(?<=sid:)([A-Za-z0-9+.\u0627-\u064a]+))',re.UNICODE)
>>> x = RE_SID.search('sid:A5ukur+de2.008x١٥١١٠٦١١٥٠٥٢٤٦٢">>')
>>> x.group('sid')
'A5ukur+de2.008x'
```

However this is not working when Persian/Arabic alphabet is combining with the latin characters and this is returning me only `A5ukur+de2.008x`.

I will be appreciated for any help.

Comment: What exactly is the pattern?

Comment: I believe this question/answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546442/python-regular-expression-with-utf8-issue - basically use `re.compile(ur'...', re.UNICODE)`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685984/using-range-in-regex-for-arabic-letters. Is it Python 2 or 3?

Comment: There can be some issues with Arabic as their Unicode Pages not not totally contiguous. You may also want to look at the Unicode Definitions as some of the letters are VERY locale specific.

Comment: I have use `\u0627-\u064a` inside my pattern like `([A-Za-z0-9\u0627-\u064a._+]*)`, but doesn't work. and in my case, is a combination of persian and latin letter. The version is 2.7.10 @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: If you use it with `re.U` option, everything will work. Also, just `.encode/decode("utf8")` every time you access the data.

Comment: Would u please to write it with the correct statement?  @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127900/can-the-a-za-z-python-regex-pattern-be-made-to-match-and-replace-non-ascii-uni/33128359#33128359), and [a similar one here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863608/regex-python-with-unicode-japanese-character-issue/32868484#32868484). [Another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34672071/python-2-re-sub-issue/34672544#34672544), a bit more complex. [Unicode with `re.finditer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207449/discover-identically-adjacent-strings-with-regex-and-python/32207506#32207506) here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tried it and I have updated my question, I am not sure how it would be worked!!

Comment: I checked: the regex just does not catch these symbols. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE3sI5/1). What are these characters?

Comment: Use `(?P<sid>(?<=sid:)([A-Za-z0-9+.\u0621-\u06FF]+))`. Check [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/KSEkhk). `\u06FF` is *Arabic Letter Heh with inverted V*. See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35581928/3832970). Please check what range you are interested in from that table.

Comment: What is this u before `test_str = u"sid:A5ukur+de2.008x١٥١١٠٦١١٥٠٥٢٤٦٢\">>'"`? Is that need to use `u`, because I am extractig the id from log, and this seems to me that I have to join it with `u`, right? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: If you extract the string from somwhere, it must be also in Unicode. u means a Unicode byte string.